# Subtracting matrix elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have one `4x3` matrix. I want to subtract every element in that matrix from each other.

I've looked around TensorFlow documentation extensively (and on SO) and noticed that there is a `tf.subtract` operator. In adding, I know that there is `tf.add_n` operator which adds all input tensors. I'm new to TensorFlow and was wondering: is there such a subtraction operator which subtracts all input tensors and if not, can you please provide an example of the fastest way to do so?

Example matrix tensor: `[[0.10, 0.20], [0.20, 0.40]]` so expanded as:

```
0.10 0.20
0.20 0.40
```

Desired subtraction: `0.10 - 0.20 - 0.20 - 0.40` with desired output as: `-.7`

Comment: What do you mean subtract every element in that matrix from each other? Can you post a sample input/output?

Comment: @chrisz Please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re describing is the opposite of the sum, substituting the opposite of the first element of the first vector.

```
tf[0][0] = tf[0][0] * -1
```

And then use

```
tf.reduce_sum() * -1
```

Comment: Please see my update. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding because this is not the desired output. Thanks

Comment: Updated the function to reduce_sum(). That should fix it